# dictionary to data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm following Wes McKinney's Data Analysis book, and he creates a similar structure of code, instead of np arrays he uses lists.

```
bills_dict = {'bills':np.random.randn(5,1)*5 + 50,
             'tips':(np.random.randn(5,1)*5 + 50)*(np.random.uniform(0.1,0.3,(5,1))),
             'dinner_time':np.reshape(np.random.choice(['Dinner','Lunch'],5),(5,1)),
             'smoker':np.reshape(np.random.choice(['Yes','No'],5),(5,1))}
```

This stage goes well, but when I try to convert into dataframe:

```
df_bills3 = pd.DataFrame(bills_dict)
```

The hell breaks loose:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-111-83469cc92eef> in <module>
----> 1 df_bills3 = pd.DataFrame(bills_dict)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    433             )
    434         elif isinstance(data, dict):
--> 435             mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    436         elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
    437             import numpy.ma.mrecords as mrecords

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype)
    252             arr if not is_datetime64tz_dtype(arr) else arr.copy() for arr in arrays
    253         ]
--> 254     return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    255 
    256 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in arrays_to_mgr(arrays, arr_names, index, columns, dtype)
     62     # figure out the index, if necessary
     63     if index is None:
---> 64         index = extract_index(arrays)
     65     else:
     66         index = ensure_index(index)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in extract_index(data)
    353 
    354         if not indexes and not raw_lengths:
--> 355             raise ValueError("If using all scalar values, you must pass an index")
    356 
    357         if have_series:

ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

So, I'm trying to pass index, maybe something like

```
index = np.reshape(np.arange(5),(5,1))
```

and it stills complains. What do?

Comment: Does simply `index=np.arange(5)` work?

Comment: Print bills_dict to make sure it can be used to create a DataFrame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently the issue is each dictionary key is a 2-D array.  You can flatten it like this:

```
bills_dict = {'bills':np.random.randn(5,1)*5 + 50,
             'tips':(np.random.randn(5,1)*5 + 50)*(np.random.uniform(0.1,0.3,(5,1))),
             'dinner_time':np.reshape(np.random.choice(['Dinner','Lunch'],5),(5,1)),
             'smoker':np.reshape(np.random.choice(['Yes','No'],5),(5,1))}

for k, v in bills_dict.items():
    bills_dict[k] = v.flatten()
    
pd.DataFrame(bills_dict)
```

As an alternative, you can change the way you create the dictionary.  Then you won't need to flatten the dictionary's values.

```
bills_dict_2 = {
    'bills': np.random.randn(5)*5 + 50,
    'tips': (np.random.randn(5)*5 + 50) * (np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.3, 5)),
    'dinner_time': np.random.choice(['Dinner','Lunch'], 5),
    'smoker': np.random.choice(['Yes','No'], 5)
}

pd.DataFrame(bills_dict_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Main issue, you are passing an associative list of matrices, not arrays. make each column an array, not a matrix.

[pd.DataFrame.from_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) alternative to default DataFrame constructor

```py
bills_dict = {'bills':(np.random.randn(5)*5 + 50),
             'tips':(np.random.randn(5)*5 + 50)*(np.random.uniform(0.1,0.3,5)),
             'dinner_time':np.random.choice(['Dinner','Lunch'],5),
             'smoker':np.random.choice(['Yes','No'], 5)}

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(bills_dict, orient='columns')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
bills_dict = {'bills':np.random.randn(5,1)*5 + 50,
             'tips':(np.random.randn(5,1)*5 + 50)*(np.random.uniform(0.1,0.3,(5,1))),
             'dinner_time':np.reshape(np.random.choice(['Dinner','Lunch'],5),(5,1)),
             'smoker':np.reshape(np.random.choice(['Yes','No'],5),(5,1))}
bills_dict['bills']
type(bills_dict['bills'])
#
bills_dict['bills'].shape 
bills_dict['tips'].shape
bills_dict['dinner_time'].shape
bills_dict['smoker'].shape
```

all of these numpy arrays are shape (5, 1), this is the problem.
bills_dict['bills'].flatten().shape #(5,)

for key in bills_dict.keys():
bills_dict[key] = bills_dict[key].flatten()

you want to use [pandas.DataFrame.from_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html)

note :  DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='columns', dtype=None)
the default value for orient is columns, no need to nominate if columns input.

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(bills_dict)
df.shape